# Linux: Contents of "global" folder synced to other folders automatically

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, links

I have a directory that has 3 sub directories.

"global_plugins", "foo", and "bar"

foo and bar both have a subfolder called "plugins".

I want the content of "global_plugins" to appear in plugins, on top of what is already in plugins, for each folder.

These are all on one local machine, and the files need to be R/W in all cases.

Comment: Adjust [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1131150/432690).

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think that this is not possible due nature of folders. But you can try couple of alternatives.

- You can write custom script that will create symlinks in `plugins`
  when you create file in `global_plugins`
- You can make symlink to `global_plugins` in both `plugins` directories
- You can make symlinks by hand

Comment: I do the 3rd already, How do I do the 1st, and 2nd doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not the best in it but this could help http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=25274