# Symlink a directory to another directory that exists with write access

Tags: linux, file-permissions, symbolic-link

Sorry for the vague title.
I have a folder `/opt/A/B/` and ideally, I want to symlink `~/B` to `/opt/A/` such that `~/B` and `/opt/A/B` are in sync.
The obvious answer would be:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/A/B
sudo ln -s ~/B /opt/A/B
```

However, consider this scenario:
A is owned by root, but B is owned by me, and I don't want to use sudo (this operation is a python script that gets run by a very big thing that doesn't have sudo).

This is another approach (remember, I have ownership of `/opt/A/B/`):

```
ln -s ~/B/* /opt/A/B/
```

But then it will go out of sync if new directories/files get written in `/opt/A/B` or `~/B`.

So my question is the following:

Is there any sudo-less way to do this?

I can use sudo for any one-time only operations that will not go in the script. If it matters, the goal is to rotate the symlink depending on certain configurations, so I do have a finite amount (specifically 3).
Note: Can also be

Comment: Somewhat related trick: *[Automatically symlink directory files into another directory](https://superuser.com/q/1121267/432690)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-time `sudo` operation:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Z /opt/A/B
```

But now the trick to rotate configs. Let `~/Z` be a symlink as well:

```
ln -s ~/B ~/Z  # it points to B
rm ~/Z
ln -s ~/C ~/Z  # now it points to C
```

Your different configs would be in `B`, `C` etc.

Comment: I don't think I mentioned this:
I have ~/B, ~/C, and ~/D

I want to swap around /opt/A/B to reference ~/B, ~/C, or ~/D

Comment: oo that's really clever. That would definitely work. Thanks!