# Combined view of multiple directories in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, samba

I have a samba server running `Armbian Buster` (`Debian 10`) on `BananaPi M1` with three disks connected to it.

`Samba` is configured to share all three disk (3 separate shares).

Disks contain folders an each of them has `folderA` and `folderB` containing files.

It looks like this:

```
Disk1 
  (Folder A - file1, file2, file3) 
  (Folder B - f1, f2, f3)
Disk2 
  (Folder A - file5, file6, file2) 
  (Folder B - f1, f4, f6)
Disk3 
  (Folder A - file2, file8, file9) 
  (Folder B - f5, f7, f8)
```

I want to be able to have a folder showing contents of `folderA` on both disk as one folder and same with `folderB`.

```
FolderA - file1,file2,file3,file5,file6,file2,file2,file8,file9
```

Why ? If I want to check if the file exists on any of `folderA`'s I have to `cd` and `ls` all of them and look if the file exists or not. Also having this kind of folder would allow me to share it as whole and not separate folders (just like libraries worked in `Windows7` - a single view of multiple folders).

For the moment I've created folders named `A` and `B` and created symlinks of all files in `folderA` & `B` on all three disks. But every time contentes of source folders change I will have to make all the changes in my "combined" folder manually - means every time I delete something from say `folderA` on `disk1` I will have to delete the symlink in `folderA`.

I would like to have a single combined folder with symlinks that would automatically reflect the contents of source folders.

Is there a way to do this without scripting (any built in command I don't know) ?

Comment: [How to mount two separate folder locations to one?](https://superuser.com/q/1171603/432690) (but I'm not sure if you can use Samba on top). Different approach: [Automatically symlink directory files into another directory](https://superuser.com/q/1121267/432690).

Comment: Thanks Kamil - I will try one of the solutions in them entioned post. Mhddfs looks promising :) Thanks again - I upvoted your answer in the linked thread !